# Jerk vegetable?

Tags: vegetarian, caribbean-cuisine, jerk

I have some friends coming over and will be cooking jerk chicken. As asked in my other question.

[Definitive Jerk Chicken](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8623/definitive-jerk-chicken)

However some of them are vegetarian. I would like to make them jerk X with X being a vegetable which could be cooked in a similar way which would taste good in jerk sauce.

Any suggestions as to what vegetable could be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with justkt, I wonder if you'd be willing to go with a vegetarian protein, rather than a vegetable--I think of seitan (made from wheat gluten) or paneer (a mild cheese, used in a lot of Indian cooking). They're both remarkably easy to make, delicious, pick up flavors well. They both have hearty, tooth textures that would be satisfying.

Comment: Paneer is absolutely wonderful!

Comment: Seitan may be more work that they want to do.

Comment: Actually, I have ordered in some Haloumi, could that be marinated too?

Comment: Haloumi could definitely be marinated.  It's going to have a stronger, saltier flavor than paneer, though, so you'll want to make sure you think your jerk marinade will compliment it.  Where paneer has an extremely mild flavor, haloumi stands on its own more.

Comment: While it does require kneading, seitan's not really hard: mix, knead, boil. (Homemade paneer: boil, drain, squeeze.)

Comment: Seitan's the first thing that came to mind for me too.

Comment: I ended up using Haloumi and it worked great, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Rather than vegetables, how about roasting up some tofu or tempeh?  Both will pick up the taste of the marinade easily.

If you want to stick with vegetables, marinate different colors of bell peppers, zucchini or yellow summer squash, eggplant and portobello mushrooms in the jerk marinade and make vegetarian kebabs.

Comment: agreed: eggplant and porotbello's were my first idea's