# How to marinate cheese

Tags: cheese, marinade

In the answers to this question [Jerk vegetable?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8624/jerk-vegetable)
one of the suggestions is to marinate some cheese.

This is not something I have heard of before. I was wondering what cheeses are suitable, and are there any special considerations that need to be made?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lot of cheeses are naturally brined (feta, for example), and marinating cheese is not much different.  For the best effect:

- Pick a porous cheese
- Cut off the edges if the cheese has a skin
- Cut into smaller pieces to increase the penetration
- Press it dry with towels (or paper towels)
- You can inject the cheese to get more flavour in it
- Marinate in flavours that compliment the cheese
- Let the cheese soak for at least 4 hours (more for less porous cheeses)

If the cheese is really wet (like feta), add weights to the drying process (like a pot or heavy plate), and let it drain until the surface feels dry.

Note that many cheeses are already salty, so balance your marinade with this in mind.

Comment: Note that this is how you marinate tofu as well.